# Dvorak layout in Emacs by default?

Tags: emacs

I recently switched to typing on Dvorak layout. But after some time, I decided to use Dvorak only in Emacs - so all other key bindings on my system would not be screwed.

So, I took the following from some question on StackOverflow.com:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after activate-input-method activate)
  (activate-input-method "english-dvorak"))
```

It switches the input method in all new buffers to dvorak. It works fine, but the there is the problem - the scratch buffer keeps it's default english layout, and all file choosing "dialogs" (C-x C-f) also keep it - which is kinda annoying, because it requires me to switch "typing mindsets" several times a minute.

Is there a way to enable the dvorak layout globally in emacs - and still keep the default shortcuts (like that C-x on default english)?

EDIT:

The answer to my problems:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (after activate-input-method activate)
  (activate-input-method "english-dvorak")) 
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (set-input-method "english-dvorak")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like (guaranteed 100% untested code):

```
(define-minor-mode dvorak-minor-mode "Use Dvorak IM." :lighter nil
  (if dvorak-minor-mode (activate-input-method "english-dvorak")))
(define-global-minor-mode dvorak-mode dvorak-minor-mode dvorak-minor-mode)
```

Comment: Strange - it looks good, but it does *nothing* - absolutely nothing. And no error, too.

Comment: @Rogach: If you read the code (and try to guess what it does based on the identifiers it uses), it only defines a (well, two) minor mode.  You then have to activate that minor mode if you want it to take effect.  E.g. add `(dvorak-mode 1)` at the end.

Comment: Ok, adding (dvorak-mode 1) made that code run, and it was not able to find the active-input-method identifier. In the meantime, I solved the problem in an other way :)

Comment: @Rogach: that was just a typo, it should have been `activate-input-method`.  Now that you mention it, my solution probably doesn't address the minibuffer case, so you might still need the `add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook`.

Comment: In Emacs 28 there is no activate-input-method, set-input-method works instead.

Comment: @Rogach: you might want to double-check; it's definitely still there in my Emacs-28.

Comment: My bad - I was looking in M-x, and since activate-input-method is non-interactive it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I use Emacs version 28 with emacsclient. I had to tweak @Stefan's answer a bit to get Emacs server to successfully start up - here's the full code I use to get dvorak enabled in all my buffers:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode dvorak-minor-mode "Use english-dvorak input method." :lighter nil
  (if (and dvorak-minor-mode (not (minibufferp)))
    (activate-input-method "english-dvorak")))
(define-global-minor-mode global-dvorak-mode dvorak-minor-mode dvorak-minor-mode)
(global-dvorak-mode t)
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda () (set-input-method "english-dvorak")))
```